# Trying to get property 'brand' of non-object (View: D:\Laravel\Laravel Internship\Laravel file\resources\views\carrental\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have two Models and both have one to many relationship with a foreign key of `VehiclesBrand` and whenever I want to get property of `Tblbrand` by using Vehicle model like `{{$vehicle->brand->BrandName }}` the error comes and the same thing when I output with the help of dd() function it returns the true answer and also when I output `Tblvehicle::all()` it returns with relations array empty I don't know why.

1.App\Models\Tblbrand

2.App\Models\Tblvehicle

Model Tblbrand:

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by Reliese Model.
 */

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Tblbrand
 */
class Tblbrand extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tblbrands';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $dates = [
        'CreationDate',
        'UpdationDate'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'BrandName',
        'CreationDate',
        'UpdationDate'
    ];
    public function vehicle(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tblvehicle','VehiclesBrand');
    }
}
```

Model Tblvehicle:

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by Reliese Model.
 */

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Tblvehicle
 * @package App\Models
 */
class Tblvehicle extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tblvehicles';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'VehiclesBrand' => 'int',
        'PricePerDay' => 'int',
        'ModelYear' => 'int',
        'SeatingCapacity' => 'int',
        'AirConditioner' => 'int',
        'PowerDoorLocks' => 'int',
        'AntiLockBrakingSystem' => 'int',
        'BrakeAssist' => 'int',
        'PowerSteering' => 'int',
        'DriverAirbag' => 'int',
        'PassengerAirbag' => 'int',
        'PowerWindows' => 'int',
        'CDPlayer' => 'int',
        'CentralLocking' => 'int',
        'CrashSensor' => 'int',
        'LeatherSeats' => 'int'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'RegDate',
        'UpdationDate'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'VehiclesTitle',
        'VehiclesBrand',
        'VehiclesOverview',
        'PricePerDay',
        'FuelType',
        'ModelYear',
        'SeatingCapacity',
        'Vimage1',
        'Vimage2',
        'Vimage3',
        'Vimage4',
        'Vimage5',
        'AirConditioner',
        'PowerDoorLocks',
        'AntiLockBrakingSystem',
        'BrakeAssist',
        'PowerSteering',
        'DriverAirbag',
        'PassengerAirbag',
        'PowerWindows',
        'CDPlayer',
        'CentralLocking',
        'CrashSensor',
        'LeatherSeats',
        'RegDate',
        'UpdationDate'
    ];

    public function brand(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tblbrand','id');
    }
    public function booking(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Tblbooking');
    }
}
```

carrental.index.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle)
    <div class="col-list-3">
        <div class="recent-car-list">
            <div class="car-info-box"> 
                <a href="{{route('vehicles-details',$vehicle->id) }}">
                    <img src="{{asset('admin/img/vehicleimages')}{{$vehicle->Vimage1 }}" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ $vehicle->FuelType }}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ $vehicle->ModelYear}} Model
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ $vehicle->SeatingCapacity }} seats
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="car-title-m">
                <h6><a href="{{ route('vehicles-details',$vehicle->id) }}" >{{$vehicle->brand->BrandName}}{{ $vehicle->VehiclesTitle }}</a></h6>
                <span class="price">Rs {{ $vehicle->PricePerDay }}/Day</span>
            </div>
            <div class="inventory_info_m">
                <p>{{ $vehicle->VehiclesOverview }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also if a given answer answers your question then don't forget to up-vote and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your relationship definition in `Tblvehicle` model. you are passing `id` as the foreign key reference in the relationship definition but `id` is not the foreign key. it seems `VehiclesBrand` is the foreign key. so pass it in the relationship definition

```
public function brand(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tblbrand','VehiclesBrand');
}
```

you can pass `id` as the third parameter which refers the primary key or other custom key of the related model. read about laravel relationship [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)